Is it a bad practice to include test-specific implementations of an API?
To summarize my case, I'm building a .NET CLI tool with a nested-commands approach, some of which are transmittable to other processes via System.Diagnostics.Process. I've written unit tests that cover a good portion of my app, and I intend to write some integration tests for some execution scenarios. However, I don't want to use specific commands to generally verify flawless command transmission, so I'm kind of leaning towards including test-specific implementation of this API. That way, I think, I can ensure command transmissibility is working correctly without having to worry about the actual implementation of certain commands. Yet, I'm not sure whether this is a reasonable approach or a bad practice.
I'm seeking guidance in this regard and would like to ask for recommendations if you think there's a better way of managing such cases.

Hm, I would try to just reference app project from test project and do all "extensions" in test project, not to include those in the app project.

Thanks for the comment @MichałTurczyn!
May I kindly ask you to elaborate further on this in an answer?
